# In jupyterNotebook Import a .csv File with python into a MongoDB

Tags: python

How do i import a .csv File into Mongo DB in jupyter Notebook (How to with .csv File with entrys >= 1.000.000) Used Chunks and no chunks etc
jhsdgijsfdhgidifjisdjfiodjiodjfidshjihiuahgsifdugh
#Code

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pandas as pd
import csv
from time import perf_counter

# Verbindung zur MongoDB erstellen
client = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
db = client["mflix"]
collection = db["test"]

# starten des Counters
t1_start = perf_counter()
#  Daten in Chuncks einlesen damit es zu keinem Overload führt
# low_memory = False setzten für große CSV Dateien, sep=',' für .csv und '\t' für .tsv
for chunk in pd.read_csv("202201-citibike-tripdata.csv", chunksize=10000, sep=',', low_memory= False):
    chunk.reset_index(inplace = True)
    data_dict = chunk.to_dict("records")
    collection.insert_many(data_dict)
# stoppen des Counters
t1_stop = perf_counter()
# Zeit in Sekunden berechnen
print(f"Maximale Dauer für Import {t1_stop - t1_start} Sekunden")

# <------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>

# Ohne Chuncks
t1_start = perf_counter()

# low_memory = False setzten für große CSV Dateien, sep=',' für .csv und '\t' für .tsv
file = pd.read_csv("202201-citibike-tripdata.csv", low_memory = False)
file.reset_index(inplace = True)

data_dict = file.to_dict("records")


collection.insert_many(data_dict)
t1_stop = perf_counter()
print(f"Maximale Dauer für Import {t1_stop - t1_start} Sekunden")
```

Comment: Please be explicit about where you need help.   Do you run out of memory loading the csv file?  Do you encounter a memory issue while writing to the mongo db?  Is it a problem with writing to mongo db?  Is it a problem reading csv?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.